# How to update UILabel that is a subview of inputView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextviewdelegate, inputview

I have UITextView where user types a text. When the keyboard is shown, I add inputView with UIlabel on it. I want this UIlabel to hold character length of the text. It seems very easy task, but unfortunatelly it does not update this word counter UILabel when user change text..

this is how I load the inputView

```
_textView.inputView = [self inputAccessoryView];
```

in inputAccessoryView I simply add UILabel as a subview. When keyboard is show, UILabel is also show with inputView. I track changes on

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

unfortunatelly the UILabel is never updated (redrawn). When I log in to console its value, the value is correct, so its updating, but the UIlabel is never redrawn and holds the default value.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How are you trying to update the label and how are you sure that the value is updated even though the UI doesn't show it?

Answer (score 0):

did you

```
_textView.delegate = self;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I know it was 5 years ago, but it might help others, who like me stumble upon your question.

I use a UIToolbar as my inputAccessoryView (in my case it has a label, a flexible separator and a button).
On textFieldEditingChanged event I rebuild part of the toolbar like this

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {

    //get a reference to the toolbar
    let toolBar = sender.inputAccessoryView as! UIToolbar

    //create a new label and set size + other properties
    toolbarLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 22))
    toolbarLabel.text = mySpecificCalculatedString(sender.text!)
    toolbarLabel.font = defaultFont(17)
    toolbarLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    let width = toolbarLabel.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxWidthForLabel, height: 0), limitedToNumberOfLines: 1).size.width
    toolbarLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 22)
    toolbarLabel.textColor = .black
    toolbarLabel.tag = 666

    //rebuild the specific tolbar item
    let customView = UIBarButtonItem(customView: toolbarLabel)
    toolBar.items![0] = customView
}
```

Note: simply changing the text of the label did not work for me either, I had to reinitialize it.

Hope it helps.